# Batch File - Attrib +r %Var1%

Tags: batch-file, attributes

I have a undoubtedly silly problem. I need to change the attribute of a file to read only. I know to use...

```
atrrib +r c:\somefile.txt
```

And it works. However in my program I want to use a variable in place of the path to be built up beforehand. Now if I write...

```
set File=c:\somefile.txt

attrib +r %File%
```

Then I get an error saying 'attrib' is not recognized as an internal or external command etc.

However if I echo %File% beforehand then I know the path to the file is correct and being read properly.

What is my error? Thanks a lot!!!

Edit:

```
set File=Main.xaml
set Folder=C:\Users\yef03111\Desktop\His0164\WINDOW\ALS026-01~EDF
set Path=%Folder%\%File%

echo %Path%
```

However if I change the echo to attrib +r and nothing else...

```
attrib +r %Path%
```

I get the 'attrib' not recognized error. This is the current example that is not working. Hope you can spot something from it!

Comment: Works fine for me on Windows 7; any other details you can provide that might lead to a view on your problem?

Comment: Does the problem persist if you run the script as Administrator?

Comment: Answer added below - problem is your use of the variable name Path....

Comment: @SomethingDark tada!! Works now. However my logged on user has the same file permissions as the administrator. I'm even part of the admin's group, so when I run as admin I don't need to enter a password, just hit enter. Can you tell why I need to run as admin for it to work? Also I found that if I put the path there instead of the variable it works without run as too. Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Path` is a system variable that tells CMD, Explorer, and CreateProcess where to look for commands.

As you are trashing the system variable CMD no longer looks in system32 for commands like attrib.

> set Path=%Folder%\%File%

As a general rule avoid likely names used by the system in naming your own things. A lot of people will do `MyFile` or `ProgPath`.

Also commands like attrib will always be found if the current directory is System32. The current directory is always searched first for commands (programs). I suspect RunAs is setting the current directory to System32.

Comment: Thanks. I will remember this for future. Great help! Works fine when I changed the variable name to %FilePath%. Good spot!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are setting an environment variable called `PATH`. This is overwriting the system `PATH` variable which contains the location of the executable files such as `attrib`. The way it works is that in order to find a program to run, the OS looks up the PATH variable and searches in the folders listed there for executable files with the name of the program you are trying to run. When you change the `PATH` variable, the OS can no longer find the `attrib` command.

Change the name of your variable from path to filepath and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your script using Cmd on windows 7. Works a treat, so I cant recreate what you are seeing.

I did quite a lot of batch scripting at one point, and I used to get random errors using standard windows notepad. Tell tail signs of issues in the script were whitespace characters. If you are using notepad, switch to using notepad++ to write this and see if you still get errors.